# Displaying name and value in two separate blocks

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, css-float

In the html below 'Rome' is appearing below 'Place' from the second line, how do I prevent that?

http://jsfiddle.net/JqxTx/21/

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either go with [hanging line indent](http://demosthenes.info/blog/50/Classic-Typography-Effects-in-CSS-Hanging-Indent) or [CSS3 columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns), though regarding the latter you'll have to do some investigation as to whether they're useful in this scenario.

I usually go with old-style

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Label</label></td>
        <td><span>Text</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

since it's simple, it works, and though there's a bit of redundant code, it doesn't promote nesting and it's not that big of a mess.
I still fail to see any good, simple equivalent CSS replacement for this layout scheme.
The best one probably is either

```
<label style="float: left; width: 20%;">Label</label>
<span style="float: left; width: 80%;">Text</span>
```

or

```
<label style="position: absolute; width: 20%;">Label</label>
<span style="display:block; padding-left: 20%;">Text</span>
```

You could probably find more [here](http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/06/10/30-best-css-forms/) or in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702181/replace-html-table-with-divs).
But they're not as good as the table because they don't adapt to the first column's contents.

Hacks like

```
<label style="float:left; height: 2em;">Label</label>
<span>Text</span>
```

or

```
<label style="display:block; float:left;">Label</label>
<span style="display:block; float:left; width:90%;">Text</span>
```

work but I wouldn't recommend them because they both rely on certain screen dimensions.

G'luck.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the `span` to a block element such as `p` and then style like

```
div label {
    float: left;
}
div p {
    margin-left: 40px;    
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/JqxTx/22/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/JqxTx/22/
Think this will work,as i made it into two blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table:

```
<table><tr valign=top><td>Place <td>Rome Rome ... Rome</table>
```

You may well have several name/value pairs, and then they make an excellent table.