# html and css - aligning row & columns of articles without using table

Tags: html, css

I've got a series of links to press articles I am publishing on a client's site (basic html and css, no php allowed).  The client would like the articles neatly lined up in nice rows and columns.  I'm trying not to use a table, but cannot seem to get things to line up correctly.  Of course the article titles are different lengths which throws everything off.

I've got a jsfiddle which demonstrates what I am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/ktpmm5/ug5s4Leq/5/

I would also like to do this without using a background image, but I can do that if need be (it might look fancier that way).  The client also wants this to be responsive, and be viewed on the usual smartphones, tablets, etc.

```
Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks-
```

Comment: I've personally came to the conclusion that using a simple table beats fighting CSS and browser support for days...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace HTML Table with Divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702181/replace-html-table-with-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the new CSS3 flexbox:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

but before you start, check if it is usable in the browsers you're developing for:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Thanks - I'll use all responses - tables short term and Css3 flexbox longer term. Appreciate the responses.